# Query regarding running background/foreground processes via c program and fork()

Tags: process, fork

Ok, my task is to write a C program that would run a particular process in background or foreground depending on whether & is the last argument or not. On googling, I found out that to run a process in background all you have to do is skip the line 'wait(&status)!=pid' in the parent process. The child process will run in the background.

That brings me to a query about fork(). When I type fork(), a child process is created. Now, my question is - Is the control of the program, right after calling fork(), passed to the child process before the parent process ALWAYS? Is it possible that the control is passed to parent process first? Or do both the processes run in parallel?

If the processes run parallel, I can see how skipping the wait part might work but not if the processes run sequentially.

For example:-

```
pid=fork()
if(pid==0) execvp("ls",argv);
else if(pid>0) return pid;
```

If suppose, the child process runs first. "pid==0" evaluates to true, execvp is called, ls is overwritten over the child process. "ls" terminates, control transfers to parent process. Here the wait command is not there and ls terminates and only then we go back to the parent process. Background working does not happen.

If parent process runs first, it sees that pid>0, control is transferred to main function. Since the wait command is not there, child process is not run at all, not at least until the parent process terminates.

So, how does it actually work? A few of my concepts might be way off the mark. if they are, kindly correct me.

Thanks.

Comment: Fork creates a new process. Both the parent and child are scheduled independently from then on, there is no "control transfers to parent". They run independently unless you explicitly wait (or use other synch. methods).

Answer (score 0):

Both parent and child processes are treated equally by the scheduler. You must not assume any predefined execution order and program synchronization if you need it.